# BJT configurations input

Tags: bjt

In all the configurations common collector, common base and common emitter, is the base always the input?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The base node is - obviously - ONE single node only.

However, a voltage is defined as the difference in potential BETWEEN TWO nodes.
As a consequence - and according to the working principle of the BJT - the voltage between the base node and the emitter is the input for ALL three configurations.

However, one of these nodes is grounded (ac wise) and , thus, defines the three basic configurations.

**EDIT (Comment):**  (Regarding the comment from Spehro Pefhany)

Also in common-base configuration, it is the base-emitter voltage that controls the collector current Ic.That means: When the base is grounded, it is the emitter voltage referenced to ground.

(After changing the PC machine a new account was automatically created and I am not yet allowed to write a "comment".)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously (?) not for common base. Because it's common.

Input is to the emitter, which give you the potential of voltage gain, not current gain. Image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_base).

[image]

Comment: I dont know about common base yet, but for the image i just added. Does the graph show a common base configuration?

Comment: @AuraDivitiae   What terminal does the base connect to in the circuit above? Ground. This terminal is common to both input and output circuits. That's why it's called common base.